# Does React Native have global scope? If not, how can I mimic it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I haven't been able to find anything like

```
$rootScope
```

for React Native and I want to share a couple variables between different Views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storing variables in the global scope is a bit of an anti-pattern in React. React is intended to be used with a one-way data flow, meaning data flows down from components to their children. This is achieved through [the passing of props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html).

In order to share a value between multiple views, you would either need to store the data on a shared parent component and pass it down as a `prop` OR store it in a separate entity that is responsible for data management. In ReactJS this is achieved through patterns like [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), but I'm not sure about the options for react-native.

Comment: Agree that this is generally an antipattern, but that doesn't mean that you should never use globals in any circumstance. React Native itself defines a global variable in Javascript called `__DEV__`. How is this done, and how can I create something similar, e.g. `__MYDEV__`? (It looks like this may not be possible, and that the closest you can get is an [environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117227/setting-environment-variable-in-react-native).)

Answer (score 8):

For example, you can export class with static properties and then import there when need.

In main.js for example:

```
export class AppColors {
    static colors = {main_color: "#FFEB3B", secondary_color: "#FFC107"}
}
```

In other file, where need to get this colors

```
import { AppColors } from './main.js';

class AnotherPage {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(AppColors.colors); // youla! You will see your main and secondary colors :)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add static methods or function in AppColors and how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1. create `ConstantFile.js` File and put this code.

```
export class ConstantClass {
    static webserviceName = 'http://172.104.180.157/epadwstest/';
    static Email = 'emailid';
    static Passoword = 'password';
}
```

Step 2. Access as like below. But before that, you need to `import` your js file to particular class file something like that

```
import { ConstantClass } from './MyJS/ConstantFile.js';

ConstantClass.webserviceName

ConstantClass.Email

ConstantClass.Passoword
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store those values in parent components state. Then pass methods changing those values via props or context / or like @Jakemmarsh suggested - use [Flux](http://makeitopen.com/tutorials/building-the-f8-app/data/)/[Redux](http://makeitopen.com/tutorials/building-the-f8-app/data/) approach.

OR, you can use [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.27/docs/asyncstorage.html). Its useful for storing app data like tokens and such.