# Setting environment variable in react-native?

Tags: react-native, environment-variables

I am using react-native to build a cross-platform app, but I do not know how to set the environment variable so that I can have different constants for different environments.

Example:

```
development: 
  BASE_URL: '',
  API_KEY: '',
staging: 
  BASE_URL: '',
  API_KEY: '',
production:
  BASE_URL: '',
  API_KEY: '',
```

Comment: you can try this `import {Platform} from 'react-native';` `console.log(Platform);`

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding your app constants and doing a switch on the environment (I'll explain how to do that in a moment), I suggest using the [twelve factor](http://12factor.net/config) suggestion of having your build process define your `BASE_URL` and your `API_KEY`.

To answer how to expose your environment to `react-native`, I suggest using Babel's [babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables).

To get this working you need to download the plugin and then you will need to setup a `.babelrc` and it should look something like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-inline-environment-variables"
  ]
}
```

And so if you transpile your react-native code by running `API_KEY=my-app-id react-native bundle` (or start, run-ios, or run-android) then all you have to do is have your code look like this:

```
const apiKey = process.env['API_KEY'];
```

And then Babel will replace that with:

```
const apiKey = 'my-app-id';
```

Comment: I just used the transform-inline-environment-variables plugin on its own; they seem to have fixed that React Native bug.

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer. Thanks @Scimonster!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in 0.36. The vars just never get read.

Comment: I am not current on 0.36. I'll try to update the response once we upgrade. If anyone else has tried upgrading, I'll take a suggestion or up vote another answer.

Comment: Im trying to get it to work with 0.38, but im struggeling to get the vars read. Trying to figure out where and how the babelrc is read to dig a bit into the problem, but I'm struggeling.

Comment: Sounds like great solution, but not works for me at RN@0.37.0. The only property on `process.env` is `NODE_ENV`.

Comment: I will need to be upgrading here soon, I'll try out a new solution here soon. Thanks @Sanczol

Comment: Does not seem to work anymore. For me the variables are undefined. Do I need to clear babel cache somehow or do something else to get this working?

Comment: See the answer below by Jack Zheng... you cannot access the variable via `process.env.API_KEY`... use `process.env['API_KEY']` instead

Comment: This seems like a great solution when debugging, will it work when building releases? You basically run gradle when releasing the app, so seems like you are out of luck with this approach. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DejanMaksimovic it has worked for me on release. When you package a release react-native's packager converts your JS, and so whenever you package your code, you need to have your ENV variables in the same process

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem was indeed elsewhere. I think it was the fact that I didn't have react-native preset installed, so transform didn't get picked up at all.

Comment: I am getting the process.env['API_KEY'] as undefined. Can anyone help me set this up

Comment: I had the same problem: undefined

Comment: Does not work for me either. Damn shame as this is exactly what I was looking for. (55.1)

Comment: Works for me in v0.56. You have to clear bundler's cache by running `react-native start --reset-cache` every time you change the environment variables.

Comment: Is there any RN configuration library that supports defaults? Like Mozilla's Convict? https://www.npmjs.com/package/convict

Comment: how can I use this when trying to release with gradle assembleRelease?

Comment: @RaulH hi were you able to use it for release build

Comment: I had the same problem.

Comment: @StevenYap I know this is pretty old, but I just wanted to point out that `process.env.API_KEY` and `process.env['API_KEY']` are equivalent in javascript

Answer (score 98):

In my opinion the best option is to use [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config).
It supports [12 factor](https://12factor.net/config).

I found this package extremely useful. You can set multiple environments, e.g. development, staging, production.

In case of Android, variables are available also in Java classes, gradle, AndroidManifest.xml etc.
In case of iOS, variables are available also in Obj-C classes, Info.plist.

You just create files like

- `.env.development`
- `.env.staging`
- `.env.production`

You fill these files with key, values like

```
API_URL=https://myapi.com
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=abcdefgh
```

and then just use it:

```
import Config from 'react-native-config'

Config.API_URL  // 'https://myapi.com'
Config.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY  // 'abcdefgh'
```

If you want to use different environments, you basically set ENVFILE variable like this:

```
ENVFILE=.env.staging react-native run-android
```

or for assembling app for production (android in my case):

```
cd android && ENVFILE=.env.production ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that in the README it states _Keep in mind this module doesn't obfuscate or encrypt secrets for packaging, so do not store sensitive keys in .env. It's basically impossible to prevent users from reverse engineering mobile app secrets, so design your app (and APIs) with that in mind_

Comment: Thing is it will not work with some frameworks like twitter which requires to have they key set as com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY in your .env

Comment: If you mean putting the key inside the Manifest, the extension supports it. It is just not described in this answer. You can use the variables in XML, Java and JS files.

Comment: react-native-config does not work with RN 0.56, it has unresolved issues and it is unmaintained for over 6 months. The issue witch kills its usage in RN is https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/issues/267, here is some hacking to make it work https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/issues/285

Comment: How does the xcode knows when you want to rollout a stage / prod version?

Comment: Wish I could upvote 100 times for this answer :)

Comment: When you mention support `12 factor`, do you mean because it allows different `.env` configurations such as `.env.development`, `.env.staging`, etc.? Thank you!

Comment: How to build iOS production? I use Xcode to build (archive), not use build command like Android.

Answer (score 81):

The simplest (not the *best* or *ideal*) solution I found was to use [react-native-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv). You simply add the "react-native-dotenv" preset to your `.babelrc` file at the project root like so:

```js
{
  "presets": ["react-native", "react-native-dotenv"]
}
```

Create a `.env` file and add properties:

```sh
echo "SOMETHING=anything" > .env
```

Then in your project (JS):

```js
import { SOMETHING } from 'react-native-dotenv'
console.log(SOMETHING) // "anything"
```

Comment: @Slavo Vojacek How do I use this to configure for example one `base_url` for both `staging` and `production`?

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x I am not quite sure I understand? Are you asking about using different `.env` files (per environment), or about _reusing_ some of your values in different `.env` files, so you don't duplicate them across, say, Staging and Production?

Comment: @SlavoVojacek I'm asking about different `.env` files per environment let's say `staging` and `production`.

Comment: @SlavoVojacek couldn't you overwrite values in a CI stage or at deployment?

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x, this solution won't allow you to define custom environments, out of the box. But it does have two environments: [development and production](https://github.com/zetachang/react-native-dotenv#can-i-use-different-env-settings-for-production-)

Comment: Please update ypur answer due to the latest changes in the package:
 
"Rename the import from 'react-native-dotenv' to '@env'."

Otherwise, it will raise an error "module fs is not found". See [this issue](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/issues/20) and the [migration guide](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/wiki/Migration-Guide).

Comment: Yes, i tried to this. Then i decided to abanton it because it doesn't work. I call everybody who makes such blugins and others to make possible simple solutions for such things. I use simpliest solution e.g in root directory conf.js: with content e.g "const Conf = {VAR1: 'value1', VAR2: 'value2'}"; export default Conf; .

Answer (score 27):

React native does not have the concept of global variables.
It enforces [modular scope](http://singlepageappbook.com/maintainability1.html) strictly, in order to promote component modularity and reusability.

Sometimes, though, you need components to be aware of their environment.  In this case it's very simple to define an `Environment` module which components can then call to get environment variables, for example:

**environment.js**

```
var _Environments = {
    production:  {BASE_URL: '', API_KEY: ''},
    staging:     {BASE_URL: '', API_KEY: ''},
    development: {BASE_URL: '', API_KEY: ''},
}

function getEnvironment() {
    // Insert logic here to get the current platform (e.g. staging, production, etc)
    var platform = getPlatform()

    // ...now return the correct environment
    return _Environments[platform]
}

var Environment = getEnvironment()
module.exports = Environment
```

**my-component.js**

```
var Environment = require('./environment.js')

...somewhere in your code...
var url = Environment.BASE_URL
```

This creates a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) environment which can be accessed from anywhere inside the scope of your app.  You have to explicitly `require(...)` the module from any components that use Environment variables, but that is a good thing.

Comment: my problem is how to `getPlatform()`. I have make a file like this but cannot finish the logic here in React Native

Comment: @DamonYuan that depends entirely on how you're setting up your packages.  I have no idea what `staging` or `production` even mean, because it's dependent on your environment.  For example, if you want different flavors for IOS vs Android then you can initialize Environment by importing it your `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` files and setting the platform there, e.g. `Environment.initialize('android')`.

Comment: @DamonYuan does what I put help at all, or do you need some more clarification?

Comment: This is very nice when you have control over the code. I'm running a third part module which relies on process.env, so...

Comment: If you create an `env.js` file be sure to ignore it from check-ins to the repository and copy the keys used, with empty string values, into another `env.js.example` file you do check-in so others can build your app more easily. If you accidentally check in project secrets consider [rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) to remove them not just from the source but the history thereof.

Comment: `React native does not have the concept of global variables`, it does. You can assign any value to global variable by doing `global.varA = 'valueA'` and you can access the value anywhere you want to

Comment: "React native does not have the concept of global variables." well when did RN stop using Javascript global object? did they get around that somehow?

Answer (score 25):

I used the `__DEV__` polyfill that is built into react-native in order to solve this problem. It is automatically set to `true` so long as you are not building react native for production.

E.g.:

```
//vars.js

let url, publicKey;
if (__DEV__) {
  url = ...
  publicKey = ...
} else {
  url = ...
  publicKey = ...
}

export {url, publicKey}
```

Then just `import {url} from '../vars'`and you'll always get the correct one. Unfortunately, this wont work if you want more than two environments, but its easy and doesn't involve adding more dependencies to your project.

Comment: do you know a way to 'foce' __DEV__ to TRUE even when creating a release build in xcode?

Comment: Nope. I just comment out the prod vars and then copy paste the dev vars into the prod section when I want to do a release build with dev variables.

Comment: I found this the most elegant solution

Comment: Not a terrible solution, but it isn't great because it only handles boolean behavior. That is, either dev or not. How would I handle more than 2 environments? You may as well use `process.env.NODE_ENV` as it provides either `development` or `production`. Most people need to lift the app using dev, qa, staging, prod, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Follow these steps

1. npm install react-native-dotenv
2. set .env file with some variable names i.e APP_NAME="my-app"
3. modify bable.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
      "envName": "APP_ENV",
      "moduleName": "@env",
      "path": ".env",
      "safe": false,
      "allowUndefined": true,
      "verbose": false
    }]
  ]
};
```

4. restart all the app
5. try this one `import {APP_NAME} from '@env'`. if this not works then do this one `const APP_NAME = process.env['APP_NAME'];`

Cheers :)

Comment: This one is perfect and easy to understand for everyone.

Answer (score 6):

i have created a pre build script for the same problem because i need some differents api endpoints for the differents environments

```
const fs = require('fs')

let endPoint

if (process.env.MY_ENV === 'dev') {
  endPoint = 'http://my-api-dev/api/v1'
} else if (process.env.MY_ENV === 'test') {
  endPoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:7001'
} else {
  endPoint = 'http://my-api-pro/api/v1'
}

let template = `
export default {
  API_URL: '${endPoint}',
  DEVICE_FINGERPRINT: Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
}
`

fs.writeFile('./src/constants/config.js', template, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }

  console.log('Configuration file has generated')
})
```

And i have created a custom `npm run scripts` to execute *react-native run..*

My package-json

```
"scripts": {
    "start-ios": "node config-generator.js && react-native run-ios",
    "build-ios": "node config-generator.js && react-native run-ios --configuration Release",
    "start-android": "node config-generator.js && react-native run-android",
    "build-android": "node config-generator.js && cd android/ && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
    ...
}
```

Then in my services components simply import the auto generated file:

```
import config from '../constants/config'

fetch(`${config.API_URL}/login`, params)
```

Answer (score 5):

The specific method used to set environment variables will vary by CI service, build approach, platform and tools you're using.

If you're using Buddybuild for CI to build an app and [manage environment variables](http://docs.buddybuild.com/docs/environment-variables), and you need access to config from JS, create a `env.js.example` with keys (with empty string values) for check-in to source control, and use Buddybuild to produce an `env.js` file at build time in the `post-clone` step, hiding the file contents from the build logs, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ENVJS_FILE="$BUDDYBUILD_WORKSPACE/env.js"

# Echo what's happening to the build logs
echo Creating environment config file

# Create `env.js` file in project root
touch $ENVJS_FILE

# Write environment config to file, hiding from build logs
tee $ENVJS_FILE > /dev/null <<EOF
module.exports = {
  AUTH0_CLIENT_ID: '$AUTH0_CLIENT_ID',
  AUTH0_DOMAIN: '$AUTH0_DOMAIN'
}
EOF
```

**Tip:** Don't forget to add `env.js` to `.gitignore` so config and secrets aren't checked into source control accidentally during development.

You can then manage how the file gets written using the [Buddybuild variables](http://docs.buddybuild.com/v6/docs/custom-prebuild-and-postbuild-steps#section-buddybuild-variables) like `BUDDYBUILD_VARIANTS`, for instance, to gain greater control over how your config is produced at build time.

Comment: overall i like the idea, but how does the `env.js.example` part work? let's say i want to launch the app in my local environment. if my `env.js` file is in gitignore and `env.js.example` is used as an outline, the `env.js.example` isn't a legitimate JS extension, so i'm just a little confused on what you meant by this part

Comment: @volk The `env.js.example` file sits in the codebase as a reference document, a canonical source of truth as to what config keys the app wants to consume. It both describes the keys required to run the app, as well as the filename expected once copied and renamed. The pattern is common in Ruby apps using the [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv), which is where I lifted the pattern from.

Answer (score 5):

IN TYPESCRIPT

1. Install library: [react-native-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv)

   ```
   yarn add -D react-native-dotenv
   yarn add -D @types/react-native-dotenv
   ```
2. Config file `babel.config.js`

   ```
   module.exports = {
   ...
     plugins: ['module:react-native-dotenv'],
   ...
   };
   ```
3. Create file `.env`

   ```
   API_URL="api.com"
   ```
4. Create folder `types`, then create file `env.d.ts`

   ```
   declare module '@env' {
     export const API_URL: string;
   }
   ```
5. Add folder `types` into the `tsconfig.json`

   ```
   {
     ...
     "compilerOptions": {
       ...
       "typeRoots": ["./src/types/"]
       ...
     }
     ...
   }
   ```
6. OK, now try it:

   ```
   import {API_URL} from '@env'
   console.log(API_URL)
   ```

Comment: getting this : @env could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules

Answer (score 4):

I use `babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables`.

What I did was put a configuration files within S3 with my different environments.

```
s3://example-bucket/dev-env.sh
s3://example-bucket/prod-env.sh
s3://example-bucket/stage-env.sh
```

EACH env file:

```
FIRSTENV=FIRSTVALUE
SECONDENV=SECONDVALUE
```

Afterwards, I added a new script in my `package.json` that runs a script for bundling

```
if [ "$ENV" == "production" ]
then
  eval $(aws s3 cp s3://example-bucket/prod-env.sh - | sed 's/^/export /')
elif [ "$ENV" == "staging" ]
then
  eval $(aws s3 cp s3://example-bucket/stage-env.sh - | sed 's/^/export /')
else
  eval $(aws s3 cp s3://example-bucket/development-env.sh - | sed 's/^/export /')
fi

react-native start
```

Within your app you will probably have a config file that has:

```
const FIRSTENV = process.env['FIRSTENV']
const SECONDENV = process.env['SECONDENV']
```

which will be replaced by babel to:

```
const FIRSTENV = 'FIRSTVALUE'
const SECONDENV = 'SECONDVALUE'
```

REMEMBER you have to use `process.env['STRING']` NOT `process.env.STRING` or it won't convert properly.

Comment: `REMEMBER you have to use process.env['STRING'] NOT process.env.STRING or it won't convert properly.`
Thanks! This is the one that trips me up!!!

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Create separate component like this
        Component name : **pagebase.js**
Step 2: Inside this use code this

```
    export const BASE_URL = "http://192.168.10.10:4848/";
    export const API_KEY = 'key_token';
```

Step 3: Use it in any component, for using it first import this component then use it.
        Import it and use it:

```
        import * as base from "./pagebase";

        base.BASE_URL
        base.API_KEY
```

Answer (score 4):

I used [react-native-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config) to set up multiple environments for my project. The README file very clearly explains how to configure the library in your project. Just make sure to implement the **Extra step for Android** section.

Also while setting up multiple environments make sure to specify the correct start commands in your **package.json**, based upon your system terminal. I developed the Android code in a windows laptop and iOS code in Macbook, so my respective start commands in package.json were -

```
"scripts": {
        "android:dev": "SET ENVFILE=.env.dev && react-native run-android",
        "android:prod": "SET ENVFILE=.env.prod && react-native run-android",
        "ios:dev": "ENVFILE=.env.dev react-native run-ios",
        "ios:prod": "ENVFILE=.env.prod react-native run-ios",
},
```

In case you just need to maintain a single .env file, consider using
[react-native-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv) as a lighter alternative, although I did face some issues in setting up multiple .env files for this library.

Comment: How do you read actual build time variables into your project? 
i.e. I may have some variables which are fine to add to those files. But some secret keys should come from the build environment?

Answer (score 3):

I think something like the following library could help you out to solve the missing bit of the puzzle, the getPlatform() function.

https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-env

```js
const EnvironmentManager = require('react-native-env');

// read an environment variable from React Native
EnvironmentManager.get('SOME_VARIABLE')
  .then(val => {
    console.log('value of SOME_VARIABLE is: ', val);

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('womp womp: ', err.message);
  });
```

The only problem I see with this, that it's async code. There is a pull request to support getSync. Check it out too.

https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-env/pull/9

Comment: Upvoted for providing an alternative approach not mentioned. No one size fits all.

Comment: The asynch pull req has been merged in

Comment: react-native-env doesn't appear to support Android. What's the point?

Answer (score 3):

hi there  if  you are  facing this issue   try   this   , this  will work  for  me ,thanks  me  later

**in   bable.js**

```
 plugins: [
      [
        "module:react-native-dotenv",
        {
          moduleName: "react-native-dotenv",
        },
      ],
    ],
```

use

```
import { YOURAPIKEY } from "react-native-dotenv";


inseted  of

import { YOURAPIKEY } from "@env";
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Expo there are 2 ways to do this according to the docs https://docs.expo.io/guides/environment-variables/

**Method #1** - Using the `.extra` prop in the app manifest (app.json):

In your `app.json` file

```
{
  expo: {
    "slug": "my-app",
    "name": "My App",
    "version": "0.10.0",
    "extra": {
      "myVariable": "foo"
    }
  }
}
```

Then to access the data on your code (i.e. App.js) simply import `expo-constants`:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export const Sample = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Text>{Constants.manifest.extra.myVariable}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

This option is a good built-in option that doesn't require any other package to be installed.

**Method #2** - Using Babel to "replace" variables. This is the method you would likely need especially if you are using a bare workflow. The other answers already mentioned how to implement this using `babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables`, but I will leave a link here to the official docs to how to implement it: https://docs.expo.io/guides/environment-variables/#using-babel-to-replace-variables

Answer (score 1):

For latest RN versions, you can use this native module: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing your app using expo(managed workflow), you will have to create a file called **app.config.js** inside the root directory of your project and add the following code to the file:

```
const myValue = "My App";

export default () => {
    if (process.env.MY_ENVIRONMENT === "development") {
        return {
            name: myValue,
            version: "1.0.0",
            // All values in extra will be passed to your app.
            extra: {
                fact: "dogs are cool"
            }
        };
    } else {
        return {
            name: myValue,
            version: "1.0.0",
            // All values in extra will be passed to your app.
            extra: {
                fact: "kittens are cool"
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Then you should start/publish your app using the command below (this will work in Windows. For other operating systems, read the article I have mentioned at the end).

> npx cross-env MY_ENVIRONMENT=development expo start/publish

This will start or publish your application using the environment variable mentioned above (MY_ENVIRONMENT). The application will load the appropriate configuration based on the environment variable. Now you can access the variable **extra** ,from your configuration, by importing a module called **expo-constants** into your project file. For instance:

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";

export default function App() {
    console.log(Constants.manifest.extra.fact);
    return (
        <>
            <View>
                <Text>Dummy</Text>
            </View>
        </>
    );
}
```

Using **Constants.manifest** we can access the object inside **extra**. So if your environment variable was *development*, this code should console.log "*dogs are cool*". I hope this was useful. For more information, go through this [article](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/).

Answer (score 0):

you can also have different env scripts: production.env.sh development.env.sh production.env.sh

And then source them in when starting to work [which is just tied to an alias]
so all the sh file has is export for each env variable:

```
export SOME_VAR=1234
export SOME_OTHER=abc
```

And then adding babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables will allow access them in the code:

```
export const SOME_VAR: ?string = process.env.SOME_VAR;
export const SOME_OTHER: ?string = process.env.SOME_OTHER;
```

Comment: Are you adding anything @chapinkapa hasn't said?

Answer (score 0):

@chapinkapa's answer is good. An approach that I have taken since Mobile Center does not support environment variables, is to expose build configuration through a native module:

On android:

```
   @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
        final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
        String buildConfig = BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.toLowerCase();
        constants.put("ENVIRONMENT", buildConfig);
        return constants;
    }
```

or on ios:

```
  override func constantsToExport() -> [String: Any]! {
    // debug/ staging / release
    // on android, I can tell the build config used, but here I use bundle name
    let STAGING = "staging"
    let DEBUG = "debug"

    var environment = "release"
    if let bundleIdentifier: String = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
      if (bundleIdentifier.lowercased().hasSuffix(STAGING)) {
        environment = STAGING
      } else if (bundleIdentifier.lowercased().hasSuffix(DEBUG)){
        environment = DEBUG
      }
    }

    return ["ENVIRONMENT": environment]
  }
```

You can read the build config synchronously and decide in Javascript how you're going to behave.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the variables with `process.env.blabla` instead of `process.env['blabla']`. I recently made it work and commented on how I did it on an issue on GitHub because I had some problems with cache based on the accepted answer. [Here](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/57#issuecomment-365557303) is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[[Source]](https://spectrum.chat/expo/general/how-do-you-manage-your-rn-environment-variables%7Efe615cd1-7130-440d-b7a2-18f8cf50022c) From what I've found, it looks like by default, it's only possible to do production and development configs (no staging or other environments) – is that right?

Right now, I've been using a environment.js file that can be used to detect expo release channels and change the variables returned based on that, but for building, I need to update the non- **DEV** variable returned to be either staging or prod:

```
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
const localhost = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'http://localhost:4000/' : 'http://10.0.2.2:4000/';
const ENV = {
  dev: {
    apiUrl: localhost,
  },
  staging: {
    apiUrl: 'https://your-staging-api-url-here.com/'
  },
  prod: {
    apiUrl: 'https://your-prod-api-url-here.com/'
  },
}
const getEnvVars = (env = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel) => {
  // What is __DEV__ ?
  // This variable is set to true when react-native is running in Dev mode.
  // __DEV__ is true when run locally, but false when published.
  if (__DEV__) {
    return ENV.dev;
  } else {
    // When publishing to production, change this to `ENV.prod` before running an `expo build`
    return ENV.staging;
  }
}
export default getEnvVars;
```

Alternatives

does anyone have experience using react-native-dotenv for projects built with expo? I'd love to hear your thoughts

https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv

Comment: You could define as many release channel names as you want, and test the name in order to define your environment variable.  Where I see the limitation is in the dev environment where releaseChannel is undefined.  So maybe you could use babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables - you could pass on environment variables in your scripts and reference process.env['VAR_NAME'] in your environment.js file if dev?

Answer (score 0):

***Do not pass these variables like*** `VAR=value react-native run-android` or `VAR=value react-native run-ios` ***.*** ***These variables are only accessible if we pass them in `start` command i.e*** `VAR=value react-native start --reset-cache`.

You can achieve this with 3 simple steps:-

1. Install `babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables` by running `npm i babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables --save-dev`.
2. Add `"plugins": [ "transform-inline-environment-variables" ]` into your `.bablerc` or `babel.config.js`.
3. Pass the variables while starting metro bundler i.e `VAR=value reacti-native start --reset-cache`, ***do not pass these variables in `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios` commands.***

**Please keep in mind that use of** `--reset-cache` **flag is required, otherwise changes in variables will not be applied.**

Answer (score 0):

After long efforts, I realized that react-native doesn't provide this feature officially. And this is in babel-ecosystem, so I should learn how to write a babel plugin...

```js
/**
 * A simple replace text plugin in babel, such as `webpack.DefinePlugin`
 * 
 * Docs: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook
 */
function definePlugin({ types: t }) {
    const regExclude = /node_modules/;
    return {
        visitor: {
            Identifier(path, state) {
                const { node, parent, scope } = path;
                const { filename, opts } = state;
                const key = node.name;
                const value = opts[key];

                if (key === 'constructor' || value === undefined) { // don't replace
                    return;
                }
                if (t.isMemberExpression(parent)) { // not {"__DEV__":name}
                    return;
                }
                if (t.isObjectProperty(parent) && parent.value !== node) { // error
                    return;
                }
                if (scope.getBinding(key)) { // should in global
                    return;
                }
                if (regExclude.test(filename)) { // exclude node_modules
                    return;
                }
                switch (typeof value) {
                    case 'boolean':
                        path.replaceWith(t.booleanLiteral(value));
                        break;
                    case 'string':
                        path.replaceWith(t.stringLiteral(value));
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.warn('definePlugin only support string/boolean, so `%s` will not be replaced', key);
                        break;
                }
            },
        },
    };
}

module.exports = definePlugin;
```

That's all, then you can use like that:

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: [],
    plugins: [
        [require('./definePlugin.js'), {
            // your environments...
            __DEV__: true,
            __URL__: 'https://example.org',
        }],
    ],
};
```

Packages that metioned by answerers are also great, and I also consult `metro-transform-plugins/src/inline-plugin.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). First install the package,

```
npm i dotenv
```

Create **.env** file and set values,

```
API_KEY=your_api_key
```

Update **.babelrc** in the **root** directory, Or create new one with these lines,

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
      "moduleName": "@env",
      "path": ".env",
      "blacklist": null,
      "whitelist": null,
      "safe": false,
      "allowUndefined": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

Then you can use them like this,

```
import { API_KEY } from '@env';

const key = API_KEY;
```

Or

```
process.env.API_KEY
```

Or

```
process.env['API_KEY']
```