# environment variables on react-native custom dependency

Tags: react-native, environment-variables

My project has a node dependency which depends on a environment variable to be set, the code is something simple as `const KEY = process.env.SOME_KEY`.
I understand that react-native has no support for traditional environment variables.

What are de options to fulfill this need and make this code work? Supposing I don't have control over the dependency's code.

Comment: Have you tried with this? [react-native-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config)

Comment: @LuisPinto that is fine when you have control over the code, I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty straight forward here, you should go with a custom babel transformer that will replace all `process.env.` calls within your code with real env values during transpilation step (during that phase there's an access to environmental variables). Transforms are also applied to the dependencies of your app which means you can apply neccessary modifications to the 3rd party code w/o actually changing it.

In order to do it, you should first create a `.babelrc` file like the one below and place it in the root of your project:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-inline-environment-variables"
  ]
}
```

Once that's done, go and npm install `babel-preset-react-native` and `babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables`.

Finally, rerun `react-native start` (basically restart the packager) and all your process.env calls will be replaced.

Comment: Thanks. I did find the same answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/37823398/1666071. If you could elaborate a little bit more and explain about the workaround that has to be done because of the way RN sets NODE_ENV, I'm willing to select you answer.

Comment: The mentioned issue and PR associated with it has been merged to master and I didn't have to perform any extra steps other than the ones described here in order to get it working.

Comment: My personal advice is to avoid Babel if you enjoy maintainable apps.