# Environmental Variable and React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Folks,

I am looking through a [Firebase blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html).

One of the items that I noticed is that they recommend (implicitly, at least) to hardcode the API keys directly into the project:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<your-api-key>",
  authDomain: "<your-auth-domain>",
  databaseURL: "<your-database-url>",
  storageBucket: "<your-storage-bucket>",,
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

I was wondering if there was any way to **avoid** having to hard-code the API keys. If I were to do this in my project, I wouldn't be able to share it on GitHub, for example. What's the equivalent, in React Native, of setting and then retrieving an environmental variable?

Comment: Related question with more upvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117227/setting-environment-variable-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

Make these details as environment data and when building the project, fill `firebaseConfig` values from the environment data.

Or, instead of using envrionment data you can store and get the data from a password protected gist maybe.

Comment: inanc - thank you for the reply. I am aware of environment variables in the context of web development, but not in the context of React Native. I know the "what" - set environment variables - but not the "how". I'm looking for the "how" part.