# React-native run-ios loading environment variables

Tags: ios, deployment, react-native, environment-variables

I want a modern way to manage environment variables for a react native mobile app.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117227/setting-environment-variable-in-react-native/37823398#37823398) explains the twelve-factor method style (which I love) which involves installing a babel plugin that transpiles references to

`const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;`

to their corresponding values as found in the process's environment

`const apiKey = 'my-app-id';`

The problem is that in order to run this with a populated environment, I need to set it like

`API_KEY=my-app-id react-native run-ios`

If I have a `.env` file with 10-20 environment variables in it, this method becomes unwieldy. The best method I've found so far is to run

`env $(cat .env | xargs) react-native run-ios`

This is a bit undesirable because developers who want to work on this package have to set up custom shell aliases to do this. This isn't conducive to a good development environment, and also complicates the build and deploy flow for releases.

Is there a way to add a hook to the `react-native-cli` (or a config file) that populates the process environment first? Like an `npm` "pre" script, but for react-native.

Comment: Alternatively, if there were just a way to populate `process.env` without the need for transpiling, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just keep a development `.env` file with the project.

Comment: @connorbode Creating a file is not my problem. Loading the env variables in `.env` into the node process is. I want a way to do this that hides the loading from the person running `react-native run-ios`.

Comment: Ah.  I'm using [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) with success.

Comment: @connorbode does that not require you to rebuild every time you change a config variable?

Comment: Probably; how often are you changing the config variables though?  Presumably you get set up in your development environment and you only change the variables when you're building for another environment.

Comment: @connorbode I think of a setting that way, but to set something like an API url or a configuration value (e.g., MAX_ITEMS_DISPLAYED) should not necessarily require a multi-minute rebuild, if that value is only used in javascript code. Would I add a hook to the node packager to update this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135430/discussion-between-connorbode-and-jeremykun).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) which is a native library and requires a link to work or [react-native-dotenv](https://github.com/zetachang/react-native-dotenv) which works just like `react-native-config` but doesn't require any native link.

It'll work fine with `.env` files set up, e.g. `.env.development` with environment variables for `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'`.

Comment: `react-native-dotenv` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Now all I need to do is figure out how to get watchman to trigger when `.env` is changed.

Comment: Good one, never tried it, I think opening an issue to see if the maintainer has some way around would help a lot.
Let me know how that works out! :)