# Set up custom developer options in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, developer-tools

Is it possible to add custom developer options to your React Native app? For instance I would like to add the possibility to change the endpoint to which the app connects so I can switch between localhost, staging, production etc. on my mobile phone

Comment: how do you build it ? Webpack ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With webpack you can use proccess.environment plugin, so you will be able to use

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev')  {
  makeYourThingIncludingRequereETC();
}
```

https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#environmentplugin

it will be transpiled to `if ('prod' === 'dev') {}` in prod environment before build and minification, which will be removed from code due to 'always false' rule.

Comment: In React Native you don't use Webpack but the React Native packager.

Comment: @Mahoni http://stackoverflow.com/a/37823398/815386 seems you have same way with your packager.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to configure your react native app for different environments is to use

[react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use webpack's define plugin:
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

If you have lots of configuration difference, configure 2 sets of webpack config, one for production, one for dev

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    PRODUCTION: true)}
```

And anywhere in your code you want to handle separation, just use a simple if statement

```
if (PRODUCTION) {
    --do your thing }
else {
    -- do your other thing}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to add some fields to a settings screen in your app with some switches and text fields to configure your developer settings. Then use React Native's `__DEV__` variable to decide whether to show these extra fields.

iOS's own Developer section is an example of this:

[image: Settings]

The advantage of this approach is that you can more finely configure individual options in your app. This is what many of the top apps do internally, whether they're using React Native or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `__DEV__` variable for this (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.

A small example:

So what you could do is to make a "DeveloperComponent".

```
...
class DeveloperComponent extends Component {
  ...
  changeEnv(env) { 
    // change used urls/keys/other based on env
  }
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <DeveleoperOption1 onPress={this.changeEnv("prod")} />
        <DeveleoperOption2 onPress={this.changeEnv("dev")} />
        <DeveleoperOption3 onPress={/* do other devlike action */} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
...
```

And add it to one of your upper components if you want it available everywhere, or in a settings page for instance. If added to an upper level, the "DeveloperComponent" could be a button, triggering an alert with the developer options.

```
  ...
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <YourRouterContainer />
      {__DEV__ && <DeveloperComponentTrigger />}      
    </View>
  );
  ...
```

or

```
  ...
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SomeOtherSettings />
      {__DEV__ && <DeveloperComponent />}      
    </View>
  );
  ...
```

And you dont seem to have to worry about devcomponents bloating your build too much:
"Using a Babel transform, we were able to remove code living behind **DEV** statements, effectively reducing bundle size, which improves JavaScript parse time"
From https://code.facebook.com/posts/895897210527114/dive-into-react-native-performance/