# How do I pass environment variables to babelrc?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I'm working on a project using both react-web and react-native(mixed app). I was able to set environment variables using [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) on web, but this seems not working with react-native.

**Meaning**:

1. npm script `cross-env NODE_ENV=development BABEL_ENV=development_web webpack-dev-server --hot --progress --config build/webpack.config.dev.js` works fine.
2. but `cross-env NODE_ENV=development BABEL_ENV=development_rn && react-native run-ios` won't work!

I got two different BABEL_ENV env settings for `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "env": {
    "development_web": {
      "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "react-transform",
          {
            "transforms": [
              {
                "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
                "imports": ["react"],
                "locals": ["module"]
              }, {
                "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
                "imports": ["react", "redbox-react"]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        ["import", { "style": "css", "libraryName": "antd-mobile" }],
        ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
      ]
    },
    "development_rn": {
      "presets": ["react-native"],
      "plugins": [["import", { "libraryName": "antd-mobile" }]]
    },
  }
}
```

How can I appoint NODE_ENV/BABEL_ENV to `development_rn` for react native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the two scripts you're not just replacing the command to run (and its options), `webpack-dev-server` with `react-native`, but you changed it to run two different commands by using `&&`. `cross-env` only applies the environment variables to the immediate command, which in your case happens to do nothing at all, as there is no command besides the environment variables (see also [`cross-env` - Gotchas](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env#gotchas)).

The `react-native` script should be:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development BABEL_ENV=development_rn react-native run-ios
```

Comment: I tried `cross-env NODE_ENV=development BABEL_ENV=development_rn npm run test`, and test script is: `echo NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV BABEL_ENV=$BABEL_ENV` it works fine, the echo result is correct. But when I change test script to `react-native run-ios`, in the react-native app they return `process.env.NODE_ENV=nothing` and `process.env.BABEL_ENV=development`. Is that mean environment variable settings are not working in react-native?

Comment: There is an [open issue #8723](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8723) for `BABEL_ENV`. As far as using environment variables in your react native code you might want to have a look at [Setting environment variable in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117227/setting-environment-variable-in-react-native), which should explain why they have the default values, but that does not solve the babel issue.