# Best way to access package.json version and build variables in react native app?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I'm building a react native iOS app, and would like to:

**1) Display the app's current version from the package.json file in the app itself.**

Specifically: Now that I've implemented [codepush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/), I want to display the current app version on the Settings page, so that app users can tell if their app has been upgraded. I currently set the version number in the package.json file and use [this](https://github.com/AndrewJack/versioning-react-native-app/blob/master/npm-version/version-ios.sh) shell script to propagate that to the xcode project. If there's a better way to manage/update a projects version number, please let me know!

**2) Execute certain .js code based on build variables from xcode.**

I have three build configurations (Debug, Staging, Release) setup in xcode, and I would like to specify the `updateDialog: true` flag to codepush only for Staging builds. I would also like to display on the settings page whether this is a Debug, Staging or Release build.

**What is the best way to accomplish these things?**

Are there best practices for setting/syncing a project's version number and accessing it within the app, or is this stuff usually just coded by hand?

Fwiw, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37823398/7515638) answer is relevant, but doesn't say what specific environment variables xcode defines that would help me here, and doesn't speak to the versioning question.

Answer (score 1):

```
async function getAppVersion() {
  const {appVersion} = await codePush.getConfiguration();

  const meta = await codePush.getUpdateMetadata();
  if (!meta) return {appVersion};

  const {label} = meta;
  return {appVersion, label};
}
```

`label` will contain codepush release label (by default v1, v2...)

For env variables [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) maybe can help you. I am using [fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/) with [increment_build_number](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/#increment_build_number) (iOS) and handmade fastlane code (Android) to autoincrement build number. To be honest I'm on my own in best practice search.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful @farwayer. One solution I had been imagining to this is to have some sort of self-made build script that gets the version from a single, definitive source (say, the package.json file) and propagates it to an env.js file, the xcode project, etc. I hesitate to do that, mostly because any time I am custom coding something that seems like a very common use scenario, I wonder if there isn't a better solution already made and/or established best practices. Eager to hear how people do this in general with JS projects, with or without codepush.

Comment: I also just found [babel-plugin-inline-json-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-inline-json-import), which may help solve how to get the package.json data into the app without doing an explicit file read.

Comment: @farwayer: could you please share your handmade Android implementation for fastlane?

Comment: @suther https://gist.github.com/farwayer/64370e04808d53e7c19f0201a954d9b0
It's old code so i'm not sure it is working now and it is best solution