# Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: process

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

My problem is when I run my react native app on Xcode (my device is 10.1.1), it successfully built but i got a red screen here

[That error pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IICeg.png)

But when I run on iOS simulator (10.3) it also successfully built and perfectly running without ERROR

Comment: share code rather than images so you could be heelped

Comment: same issue here after upgrading to latest RN 0.51

Answer (score -1):

You must be setting environment variables.  This answer should help you:

[Setting environment variable in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117227/setting-environment-variable-in-react-native)