# Passing Environment Variable to React Native Main File

Tags: javascript, node.js, xcode, react-native, environment-variables

I'd like to get in my RN app a variable from the environment somehow.

I've tried few things like: `MY_VAR=foo node...` this doesn't pass my JS file

I've tried using the `--root` option in RN CLI but this doesn't give me a complete solution as when using xcode to actually run the code with the bundler, they run, hard-coded `index.js`

What are my options?

I need to know somehow - where this code runs - which for it, to my understanding i need to pass some environment variable somehoe

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/33117227/1985912 ?

Comment: This explains how environment variables work for React apps https://medium.com/@tacomanator/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the method you create your RN app, but here are the options for both:

if using react-native init:
react-native-config, it's an easier set up than so far what i read.
-setup .env.dev and a few others you want. yarn add react-native config, set up using gradle, IOS has another method so read through the documents. then run ENVFILE=.env.dev react-native run-ios

create-react-native-app:
You may have the webpack, which means it would help you.

If you decided to eject your app from create-react-native-app, please go with react-native-config.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/

Good luck!