# I installed react-native using npx. When I run npx react-native run-android it gives me following error. IT open AVD but not showing application

Tags: react-native

[image]

Following screen shot is error, Avd is running but application is not installing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting environment variable in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117227/setting-environment-variable-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2):

The error saids about JAVA_HOME. Are you done setting up environment valuable?

Please see the official documentation:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

---

3. Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable
   The React Native tools require some environment variables to be set up in order to build apps with native code.

- Open the Windows Control Panel.
- Click on User Accounts, then click User Accounts again
- Click on Change my environment variables
- Click on New... to create a new ANDROID_HOME user variable that points to the path to your Android SDK:
  ANDROID_HOME Environment Variable

The SDK is installed, by default, at the following location:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk
```

You can find the actual location of the SDK in the Android Studio "Settings" dialog, under Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK.

Open a new Command Prompt window to ensure the new environment variable is loaded before proceeding to the next step.

Open powershell
Copy and paste Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\ into powershell
Verify ANDROID_HOME has been added

4. Add platform-tools to Path

- Open the Windows Control Panel.
- Click on User Accounts, then click User Accounts again
- Click on Change my environment variables
- Select the Path variable.
- Click Edit.
- Click New and add the path to platform-tools to the list.

The default location for this folder is:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

Comment: I already did it but it gives me same error.

Comment: Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED it gives me new error like this