# How to use environment variables in React Native (release)

Tags: react-native, environment-variables

I'm trying to understand how can I use environment variables in React Native on release. I know to use it on development (just creating a .env file) but when I publish some app at the Play Store, do I have the option to set some env. var? Otherwise I will need to publish the .env too? It's secure?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117227/setting-environment-variable-in-react-native) answer your question?

Comment: Hi @Rohit, Thank you for your reply! Actually I didn't get it. If I create a .env file, it will be exposed on release? I mean, if someone try a reverse engineering in my code, my env. var will be discovered?