# setting up .env in react native

Tags: react-native, environment-variables

Im trying to set up my env in react-native.
I have install "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1".

In my babel.config.js I have the following:

```
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  plugins: [
    [
      "module:react-native-dotenv",
      {
        moduleName: "@env",
        path: ".env",
        blacklist: null,
        whitelist: null,
        safe: false,
        allowUndefined: false,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

I have a .env file in my root directory, inside i have

```
TEST_API = 123
```

in my file that I want to use the env, I imported it like this:

```
import {TEST_API}
```

when I try to use it {TEST_API} it does not work.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72543130/10776847) answer, that solves the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one:

```
import {TEST_API} from '@env';
```