# Different API URL depending on React Native Expo environment

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

When I am developing my React Native expo iOS app on my dev machine, I want the `API_URL` variable to be `http://localhost:3000`. On the other hand, it should be `https://api.website.com` when the app is built.

Or something similar where the app can detect the environment it is running in, whether its in dev mode or a published version downloaded from the app store, and use the correct `API_URL` value.

How can we let this happen automatically? Looked into `expo-constants`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting environment variable in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117227/setting-environment-variable-in-react-native)