# How to use REACT_ENV_SECRET in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, environment-variables, google-secret-manager

My app is working fine locally. I'm using ReactJS.

For instance

```
const currentDBAPI = process.env.REACT_APP_DB_API
```

Works as expected.

I have created the secrets in the secret manager.

However it seems like once my app is deployed, react is unable to read these secrets.
I'm getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
```

I was looking at the firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#secret_parameters)
It looks like the procedure is for NodeJS, Not sure if it's the same for React but I have tried to install the firebase-functions package. and follow the procedure.

I'am deploying my app using Github action and the deployment fail because it require the async_hooks package.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in '.../firebase-functions/lib/common'
```

If I install the async_hooks package I get the same error.

After some more reading I found that this package is for server side and specific to NodeJS.

How can I access my secret using react?

Update:

since the app is built and deployed in Github actions
I have added the secrets there.

```
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile && yarn build
        env: 
          REACT_APP_DB_API: '${{ secrets.REACT_APP_DB_API }}'
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_project-id }}'
          projectId: my-project-id
```

But the result remain the same

Comment: React runs on devices. Any information it requires to operate needs to be present at build time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting environment variable in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117227/setting-environment-variable-in-react-native)

Comment: Thanks Phil. This is react-native specific. Is it the same procedure for plain react? I'm using "react": "^18.2.0",

Comment: Why did you tag this with [tag:react-native] if it wasn't? And yes, the requirement is the same; env vars need to be known at build time

Comment: does this mean they have to be define in my workflow where it gets built?

Comment: Yes. Have you actually defined the `secrets.REACT_APP_DB_API` in your Github repo? See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#creating-secrets-for-a-repository

Comment: I did set them in Github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that the secrets must be set in both workflows to work.

Firebase use a workflow on PR and on Merge, at least in my setup. Setting the secrets only in the PR workflow did not work. I had to set them in both workflows.

Note that it will also take some time before the secrets are available. On my first page load, I still got the error. I had to refresh a few time for them to get picked up.